# srand() range not as intended c++

Tags: c++, random, range

I am trying to generate random 9 digit numbers but for some reason my number is always 1000*****. I feel like my srand is good, but something else must be going on?

```
int SSN = (rand() % 899999999) + 100000000;
```

Comment: Think about the sizes of your types...

Comment: If you can use C++11 or even TR1 then check out `<random>`. It's very good.

Comment: @CarlNorum Don't think it is a problem with the size of an int, but I do think it is the limit on rand(). I will just write a random gen with ascii. Thanks. "A 32-bit unsigned int has a range from 0 to 4,294,967,295"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that `RAND_MAX` is considerably *less* than a nine-digit number.  Simply put: the values generated by `rand()` are too small for your purposes.  You'll need to use a different RNG.

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't aware there was such a thing. Guess I should have checked. Alright thanks. Are there other random generators in c++ or do I have to write my own?

Comment: @BenjyKessler - Usually, yes, but [not always](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_396.html).

Comment: Ah OK, just want to save you the lookup :)

Comment: @Xerunix yes, the `<random>` header was added in C++11 (although many compilers had it available earlier, as part of TR1).